# How to manage apostrophes in Php

Tags: php

I'd like the search and replace values to contain apostrophes. How can the array be edited to allow this?

Much Appreciated.

```
function replacecategories($value) {
//here are predefined values
$predefined = array(
array(
'search'=>'Here's an example',
'replaceWith'=>'There's an example'
)
);
//search and replace
foreach ($predefined as $item) {
$search = array_map('trim', explode(',', $item['search']));
$value = str_replace($search, $item['replaceWith'], $value);
}
return $value;
}
```

Comment: You need to either: a) Use double quotes `"There's an example"` or b) escape the apostrophe `'There\'s an example'`.

Comment: *You are too kind* @RocketHazmat

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Just one of my many flaws.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Flaws do find their way into people's hearts ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked :)

Comment: Great, yet you do know that error reporting would have caught that syntax error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your correctly, all you need to do is, either add a backslash to escape the apostrophe in your example as shown below or redefine the variables with double quotes ("Here's..."):

```
function replacecategories($value) {
    here are predefined values
    $predefined = array(
        array(
            'search'=>'Here\'s an example',
            'replaceWith'=>'There\'s an example'
        )
    );
    //search and replace
    foreach ($predefined as $item) {
        $search = array_map('trim', explode(',', $item['search']));
        $value = str_replace($search, $item['replaceWith'], $value);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
  'search'=>"Here's an example",
  'replaceWith'=>"There's an example"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophes have special meaning in any language. In order to make it actually write out the apostrophe, you need to escape the special character by using the backslash `\'`.

Or encapsulate the string in double quotes.